the behavior of the Fourier series partial sum
Consider the Fourier series partial sum $S_n(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ where $S_n(x)$ is the partial sum of the Fourier series representation of a function $f(x)$ defined on a $2\pi$ periodic interval.
The problem statement indicates that $\int_0^t |\phi(u)| du = o(t \ln t)$ as $t \to 0^+$, where $\phi(t)$ is defined as
$$
\phi(t) = f(x+t) + f(x-t) - 2s(x)
$$
$s(x)$ is a function which makes $\phi(t)$ satisfy the indication. We have got the theorem which tells that
$$S_n(x)-s(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}\phi(t)\mathrm{d} t$$
What I eager to prove is $S_n(x) = O(\ln n)$ whatever $x$ is.
Here is my attempt.
$$
\int_0^\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}\phi(t)\mathrm{d} t = O(n)\int_0^\frac{1}{n}\phi(t)\mathrm{d} t = o(n\frac{1}{n}\ln n) = o(\ln n)
$$
Denote $\Phi(t) = \int_0^t |\phi(u)| du$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}}}^\frac{1}{\ln n}\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}\phi(t)\mathrm{d} t &= O(1)\int_{e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}}}^\frac{1}{\ln n}\frac{|\phi(t)|}{t}\mathrm{d} t\\
&= O(1)\int_{e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}}}^\frac{1}{\ln n}\frac{1}{t}\mathrm{d}\Phi(t)\\
&= O(1)\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}\Big|_{e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}}}^\frac{1}{\ln n} +O(1)\int_{e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}}}^\frac{1}{\ln n}\frac{\Phi(t)}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&= o(\ln n) +o((\ln n)^2\Big|_{e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}}}^\frac{1}{\ln n})\\
&= o(\ln n)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\int_\frac{1}{\ln n} ^\pi\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})t}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}\phi(t)\mathrm{d} t &= O(1)\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}\Big|_\frac{1}{\ln n}^\pi +O(1)\int_\frac{1}{\ln n}^\pi\frac{\Phi(t)}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&= o(\ln\ln n) +O(1)\frac{1}{t}\Big|_\frac{1}{\ln n}^\pi = O(\ln n)
\end{align*}
However, I am having trouble rigorously establishing the $O(\ln n)$ bound for $S_n(x)$ over the interval $(1/n, e^{-\sqrt{\ln n}})$. Can someone provide guidance or insights on how to approach this analysis?
I would greatly appreciate any help in addressing this technical challenge.
